# Regular Expression to find & replace specific substring

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want regular expression to find & replace first and third `rownum` word in the below-given string with the word `NONE`.

```
String str = "select dummy,rownum,rowid as \"rownum\",rownum as order_number from dual";
```

I have tried below regular expression but it replacing the comma `,` before or after the word `rownum`

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)[^\"A-Z0-9]rownum[^$\"A-Z0-9]"," NONE ")
```

Actual Output : `select dummy NONE rowid as "rownum" NONE as order_number from dual`

Expected Output : `select dummy,NONE, rowid as "rownum",NONE as order_number from dual`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid replacing `"rownum"` because it is surrounded by `"` then you can use [look-around](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms to forbid `"` before or after it like

```
String str = "select dummy,rownum,rowid as \"rownum\",rownum as order_number from dual";
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)(?!<\")\\brownum\\b(?!\")"," NONE ");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output: `select dummy, NONE ,rowid as "rownum", NONE  as order_number from dual`

But that solution is valid only for this particular scenario. If you have other ones you should search for SQL parsers instead of RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it's works

```
str = str.replace("rownum", "NONE");
str = str.replace("\"NONE\"", "\"rownum\"");
```